# Search by record id with ultrasphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ultrasphinx

I'm trying to search by record id with ultrasphinx on Rails 2.3.8

In my model i tried the following:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   is_indexed :fields => [{:field => 'id', :as => 'offer_id'}]
end
```

and

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   is_indexed :fields => ['id']
end
```

And I search with

```
Ultrasphinx::Search.new(:query => "1691")
```

It doesn't return any results, while searching for other indexed fields does.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. a blast from the past.

Whilst I shifted to ThinkingSphinx after starting off with UltraSphinx, are you sure that you shouldn't be using

```
class Offer > ActiveRecord::Base
   is_indexed :fields => ['id']
end
```

maybe try that for now and then figure out how to do the AS after.

Comment: i tried that too and it didn't work, i will edit my question to make that clear

Comment: Can you search for another field in the db? like, add 'name' to that array and then search, to see if the record comes up. Any errors? are you restarting the sphinx after each update here?